# Problem in accessing Services Panel Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, services, control-panel

I have Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit installed and am having problems accessing the Services Panel from the Administrative tools option. The problem is that the Services Panel is showing a blank screen when the default Extended option is selected.

I am unable to figure out the problem that whether it is related to the installation of windows 7 or any file goes corrupt which I am not aware of.

[image]

Any ideas are welcome as I am unable to find where the problem is, and hope to avoid having to format and reinstall the system.

Answer (score 1):

click the "Standard" tab (on the bottom), i've faced this before, and the list will shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Does the standard tab work? (You need to look at the service's properties to get to the help shown in the left pane in extended view.)

When you open Services is the CPU or Hard Disk running slow (i.e. could it just be taking a long time to populate)?

Comment: Sir

thanks for your comments, the standard tab works, but the problem is that is there any thing missing from my side or only i am facing this problem or say whether i have to reinstall the OS.

isn't there any solution or patch or workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
sfc /scannow
```

Reference:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833